# Add a parameter to a link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript/jQuery. I have the following HTML code that's automatically generated by framework.

```
<tr class="alternate-row">
    <td>17 July, 2012</td>
    <td>AM Shipment</td>
    <td>Generated</td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="" id="ListTruckSheets_o_7" class="basic-form" onsubmit="javascript:submitFormDisableSubmits(this)" name="ListTruckSheets_o_7">//I have the name of this form.
            <input type="hidden" name="shipmentId"  value="10310" id="ListTruckSheets_shipmentId_o_7">
            <input type="hidden" name="Report" id="truckSheet_o_7" onclick="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, 10310);">
            <input type="hidden" name="abstractReport" id="routeAbstract_o_7" onclick="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, 10310);">
            <input type="hidden" name="milkDeliverySchedule" id="deliverySchedule_o_7"  onclick="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, 10310);">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancelShipment" id="ListTruckSheets_cancelShipment_o_7">
        </form>
        <td>
            <a class="buttontext" href="/myportal/control/KVGenerateTruckSheet.txt?shipmentId=10310&amp;reportTypeFlag=trucksheet"  target="_blank" onclick="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, 10310);" title="Report">Truck Sheet Report</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="buttontext" href="/myportal/control/KVGenerateTruckSheet.txt?shipmentId=10310&amp;reportTypeFlag=abstract" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, 10310);" title="Abstract Report">Route Abstract Report</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="buttontext" href="/myportal/control/MilkDeliveryScheduleReport.txt?hipmentId=10310&amp;reportTypeFlag=milkDeliverySchedule" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, 10310);" title="Milk Delivery Schedule">Delivery Schedule</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="/myportal/control/cancelLMSShipment" target="_blank"    onsubmit="javascript:submitFormDisableSubmits(this)" name="ListTruckSheets_o_7_0_o_cancelShipment">
                <input name="shipmentId" value="10310" type="hidden">
            </form>
            <a class="buttontext" href="javascript:document.ListTruckSheets_o_7_0_o_cancelShipment.submit()">Cancel</a>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Using onclick I have called a JavaScript function which gets the url and add a parameter to it. I have the name or Id of the form('ListTruckSheets_o_7'). Using form name or Id I need to find the parent tr and identify the right td I want and set parameter to its url. This is the code I am currently messing with.

```
function setSelectedRoute(existingUrl, shipmentId) {
     var form = $("input[value=" + shipmentId + "]").parent(); //formName: ListTruckSheets_o_7
     var routeId = form.find("option:selected").text();
     var resultUrl = existingUrl + "&facilityId=" + routeId;
     $('.buttontext').attr('href', resultUrl); // this is setting resultUrl to all the .buttontext class elements but I need to set resultUrl to only specific selected td.
}
```

So, may be, I need to find the parent tr and get back to the specific td and set resultUrl to it. I have no idea how to do it. I hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: where are your options you are getting the text from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this:

```
form
  .closest('tr')   // go parent tr of form
  .find('.specific_selected_td') // find td, here specific_selected_td is 
                                 // assumed class to selected td
                                 // you may have something different 
  .find('a')  // find anchor tag within that specific td
  .attr('href', resultUrl); // set href
```

### After edit

Change

```
$('.buttontext').attr('href', resultUrl);
```

to

```
$(existingUrl).attr('href', resultUrl);
```

Here, `existingUrl` refers to the clicked `a`.

Comment: Hi.. I have a new problem now. "attr('href', resultUrl);" is setting new url. but on each click parameter('routeId' the parameter I am appending to the 'existingUrl') may change. so, On each click I need to replace the old parameter with new one Or I may reload the page but the problem with reloading is that the user may not know what dropdown element they have previously selected. Any ideas on how to do it. Thanks in advance..